# How to Implement Resume from Last Checkpoint for Powerexchange CDC sessions?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange, oracle-cdc

We are having 37 Sessions, each sessions having tables varying between 20 to 25, our Target DB is Greenplum. Due to huge queries running at different times on DB few segments nodes are going down so few of our CDC sessions gets failed.

So, we are planning to enable Resume from Last Checkpoint for CDC sessions. Do we need to check "Enable HA recovery" at workflow to use Resume from Last Checkpoint for Sessions?

Answer (score 0):

The workflows should be started in warm mode, this way it automatically takes cares of resume from last point. 
Please note that if you started the PowerExchange logger in cold mode, you need to start the logger also with cold mode.

A Restart folder is created at $INFA_HOME/server/infa_shared/ which stores the init and term tokens for workflow to resume from last failure.